# How to actually use ZeroClipboard in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, zeroclipboard

I just can't get this thing. How is ZeroClipboard supposed to work? Why does it need to move the flash-element over the copied text?

I've read this thing: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions

Can someone provide me a short snippet, which makes it possible to copy a text in variable to users clipboard, when user clicks a link. Is this even possible? I don't care, if it doesn't work on all browsers (IE6 for example).

I'm using jQuery.

Comment: Looking at that page, did anyone else notice that IE was called "Internet Exploder"?

Comment: I think it's the correct term for the browser, but has someone some time to help me? :)

Comment: @ Eric + 500 for seeing that :) (oh well i can just upvote the comment)

Comment: ZeroClipboard is no longer supported, zclip is the new one. Different syntax, but it's still easy to use.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "minimal example" code given on the page you link to (http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/wiki/Instructions#Minimal_Example) appears to be what you want.  I've copied it here and altered it to demonstrate putting text into a variable and then copying that text to the clipboard, since that's what you're interested in.  Note that, in real life, what you'd presumably want to do is call the `clip.setText()` part within some function, since you might not know, at the point when the page is first loaded, what text you want to copy.

```
<html>
<body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

        <div id="d_clip_button" style="border:1px solid black; padding:20px;">Copy To Clipboard</div>

        <script language="JavaScript">
                var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
                var myTextToCopy = "Hi, this is the text to copy!";
                clip.setText( myTextToCopy );
                clip.glue( 'd_clip_button' );
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The flash element doesn't need to be "over the copied text"; it needs to be "glued" to whatever DOM element you want your user to manipulate -- most likely a button to click.  The reason is that Javascript doesn't have access to the clipboard, so you need to use Flash instead.  But Flash can only operate on the user's machine in response to a user's click -- so you "trick" the user into clicking on the Flash by making it an invisible overlay over an HTML element.

I'll note that while the particular example of copying to the user's clipboard is probably benign, this approach troubles me, as it wouldn't be hard to imagine the hidden flash element doing more malicious thing.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your great answer! Any change of getting some sample code to paste? :)

Comment: OK, added sample code copied and slightly modified from the instruction page.

Comment: This is not a jQuery solution ;)

Comment: Can anyone help me to get this work with the fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/Vr4Ky/1/

Comment: Joshc -- the version of ZeroClipboard that you've included in your fiddle does not appear to be the same version discussed in the link (in the original question).  That version uses very different setup code, discussed at https://github.com/jonrohan/ZeroClipboard/#readme

Comment: So there is no way to copy text to clipboard after document is loaded (without user interaction and any sort of clicking)?

Comment: it's working fine in http://localhost:4586/sample/sample/html but its doesn't work in file:///D:/newFolder/Sample/Sample.html. how to run it in file:// mode?

Comment: karthik - browsers often block javascript when running as file://.  Here's some instructions to turn this off in Chrome (when you're done, turn it back on!!): http://jamisondance.com/post/12857366951/running-local-javascript-files-in-chrome/

Comment: I am running on localhost and it's not working for me, when I right-click on the element, I get a grayed movie not loaded

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more complex jquery example. Copy the text when

```
  <script language="JavaScript">
            ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('zeroclipboard/ZeroClipboard.swf');
        $(document).ready(function(){
              $(".clickme").each(function (i) {
                    var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();

                    var myTextToCopy = $(this).val();
                    clip.setText( myTextToCopy );
                        clip.addEventListener('complete', function (client, text) {
                 alert("Copied text to clipboard." );
                });
                    clip.glue( $(this).attr("id") );



              });


        });

    </script>



<?php
//these text boxes were in a loop
for($i=0;$i<10;$i++)
    echo "<input type=\"text\" id=\"x$i\" class=\"clickme\" value=\"$value"\" />";

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This code only works in my setup together with chrome when I have a  tag in my body-area like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js-file-doesnt-exists-404.js"></script>
<div>
......
some stuff here
......
....
</div>
...some more stuff....
<the button>
....
```

when the file-include is removed the button is not working.... really strange

Answer (score 1):

The current version of ZeroClipboard actually contains [a bug](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/issues/detail?id=76) that would cause an JS error using the script suggested by JacobM - in the following scenario:

1. Create a reference to the ZeroClipboard.Client() returned from the new constructor. (e.g. var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();)
2. Set the text by doing clip.setText("string");
3. Change the DOM (hide the flash movie or an ancestor element)
4. Set the text again by doing clip.setText("some other string")

To avoid causing errors, the mouseover event listener should instead be used to set the text:

```
<html>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ZeroClipboard.js"></script>

    <div id="d_clip_button">Copy To Clipboard</div>

    <script language="JavaScript">
        var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client(),
            myTextToCopy = "Hi, this is the text to copy!";                    
        clip.glue('d_clip_button');
        clip.addEventListener('onMouseOver', clipboardEvent);
        function clipboardEvent() {
            clip.setText( myTextToCopy );
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```