# Clipboard in .Net VB.NET web forms

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, clipboard

How to copy a text in asp.net page into Clipboard using vb.net code-behind ?
And what libraries to import ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't copy text into clipboard from serverside because *client*'s memory belongs to the client. You must use javascript for this purpose and that's browser dependent.

- Here is a SO-link that'll help you to get started: [how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-clipboard-in-javascript)
  They recommend to use [zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/), i have no experiences with it.
- Here is another SO-link with a simple example: [how-to-actually-use-zeroclipboard-in-jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805009/how-to-actually-use-zeroclipboard-in-jquery)

What you can do from serverside is to [register a client script-block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/btf44dc9.aspx) that will be executed on load of your webform to copy the text into clipboard as soon as possible.