# How to use Zeroclipboard

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, zeroclipboard, zclip

I am trying to use either one of these:

http://www.steamdev.com/zclip

http://davidwalsh.name/clipboard

It seems their tutorial is missing some important part as when I test it, nothing happens. The code in which I will integrate them is inside a php loop which creates button depending on the number of db rows like this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

echo "<button onclick=do_that_zclip_function('different_parameter_for_every_button')></button>";
}
```

So first, how do I successfully run ZeroClipboard? Then how do I put it in that php code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805009/how-to-actually-use-zeroclipboard-in-jquery

Comment: Where can I get ZeroClipboard.js? The links on those are not working anymore.

Comment: http://zeroclipboard.org/